# How to make multiple copies of functions and asynchronously invoke it in C

Tags: c, asynchronous, function-pointers

Lets suppose we have a function pointer

```
int (*functionPtr)(int);
functionPtr = &doSomething;
```

Assume I keep receiving a stream of ints: 58,63,85,1000,8555,-9,-10.....
The stream comes in at high speed and could spread the entire range of int from INT_MIN to INT_MAX.

If I invoke it like this one after the other, things become very very slow:

```
int result = (*functionPtr)(intvar)
```

Instead what Id like to do, inside the code of course, is to be able to make N copies of the function that functionPtr points to and save pointers to those N copies, perhaps in an array.

Then I would like to invoke those copies concurrently and asynchronously using the call format like this:

```
(*functionPointer[N])(intvar) //Syntax might be little off, but you get the idea.
```

Is there any method or discipline in C to go about achieving this?

Comment: What would the copying part accomplish compared to running `(*functionPtr)(intvar)` multiple times concurrently? Do you need each one to have its own globals/statics because it’s not normally thread-safe, or…?

Comment: maybe try threads? not sure the overheads involved would outweigh the benefits though

Comment: @Ry- Its actually a good question, but the hope is that parallelism achieved generates more performance gain than running serially. Not sure about spawning more threads for this, Overhead may or may not be worth it.

Comment: Why are you using function pointers? Please do not use function pointers unless it is absolutely necessary. They just make the code more complicated.  Perhaps look into thread pools

Comment: If the function is slow then every time you get another number fork a process to execute the function then wait on it's result. Copying the function is not going to give any performance gains

Comment: @Ace, you seem not to be appreciating that parallelism is an entirely separate thing from having "copies" of a function.  You certainly can have multiple copies of the same function with different names, but that provides no particular advantage for parallelization.  In standard C, multithreading is your one available mechanism for both parallelism and asynchronous behavior.  In typical hosted environments, you can also use multiprocessing, but that is not part of C itself, and it is usually heavier-weight.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am seeing your point. Indeed multiple invocations of multiple copies of same function can still end up being synchronous, if done in the same thread.

Comment: My idea really was to avoid overhead of Posix thread creation. Wanted to outsmart the compiler, but increasingly looks like I was naive....

Comment: @Ace, if there were such an alternative then it would be called "multithreading", and people everywhere would use that style of multithreading instead of pthreads (or C11 threads).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is it possible to define logic in one single method and use it in N posix threads? So that when they are spawned the same logic should exec in parallel.

Comment: Yes, @Ace, absolutely.  When you start a thread you specify its entry function.  You can specify the same function to an arbitrary number of threads, whether they run concurrently or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a copy of a function. If you want to run the same function in multiple threads, then just do that. Each call to the function will have its own copy of the parameters passed to it, and its own execution stack (meaning its own local variables.)